# Android websocket sockjs client for java spring based webserver

Tags: java, android, spring, websocket, sockjs

I am using Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE and my server configured to use websocket approach based on SockJs and STOMP protocol from here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html, here my simple xml configuration on server side:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/hello" allowed-origins="*">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

So my question about where I can find any **android** sockjs compliant client or it is not possible ? Please suggest me other approachs. Thanks for help.

Comment: A dup for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809420/android-websocket-sockjs-client-for-java-spring-based-webserver ?

Comment: @Dmitro did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refused from using Spring websocket support in favor of [crossbar](http://crossbar.io/) that has a client for android.